# Cycle pictures using an array in JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

this works on a button click and that is how it is meant to be. The problem lies in the fact that it uses hidden images, instead of images stored in an array. Could you please show me how to do it so that it is images stored in an array.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="splash">
         <img src="TrafficLightRed.gif" alt="" id="mainImg">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            <button id="clickme" onclick="changeLight();">Click to change</button>
            <img src="TrafficLightRed.gif" hidden>
            <img src="TrafficLightYellow.gif" hidden>
            <img src="TrafficLightGreen.gif" hidden>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        function changeLight() {
            var currentImg = document.getElementById("mainImg");
            for(var i=1;i<3;i++) {
                if(document.images[i].src == currentImg.src) {
                    currentImg.src = document.images[i + 1].src;
                    return;
                }
            }
            currentImg.src = document.images[1].src;
        }
     </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would store the image's `src` in an array:

```
imagesArray = ["TrafficLightRed.gif","TrafficLightYellow.gif","TrafficLightGreen.gif" ];
```

And use the array in place of `document.images[i + 1].src`:

```
...
   for(var i=0;i<imagesArray.length;i++) {
        if(imagesArray[i] == currentImg.src) {
            currentImg.src = imagesArray[i];
            return;
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
...
<script>
    var images = ["TrafficLightRed.gif", "TrafficLightYellow.gif", "TrafficLightGreen.gif"];
    var currentIndex = 0;

    function changeLight() {
        var currentImg = document.getElementById("mainImg");
        currentImg.src = images[(currentIndex++) % images.length];
    }
 </script>
 ...
```

Now you can add more images to array `images` and it will automatically loop through this array.